# Selectively recurse into left or right subtree of a binary tree using a catamorphism (or any recursion scheme)

Tags: haskell, time-complexity, binary-tree, recursion-schemes

I'm trying to implement a binary search tree (or set) using fixed points of functors. I've defined my fixed point as follows:

```
newtype Fix f = In (f (Fix f))

out :: Fix f -> f (Fix f)    
out (In f) = f    
    
-- Catamorphism    
type Algebra f a = f a -> a    
    
cata :: (Functor f) => Algebra f a -> Fix f -> a    
cata f = f . fmap (cata f) . out
```

To make the binary tree, I'm using a red-black tree like so:

```
data NodeColor = Red | Black deriving (Eq, Show)    
    
data RedBlackTreeF a r = EmptyRedBlackTreeF | RedBlackTreeNodeF NodeColor r a r deriving (Eq, Show)
    
instance Functor (RedBlackTreeF a) where                                             
        fmap _ EmptyRedBlackTreeF = EmptyRedBlackTreeF                               
        fmap f (RedBlackTreeNodeF color r1 a r2) =                                   
                RedBlackTreeNodeF color (f r1) a (f r2)                              
                                                                                     
type RedBlackTreeF' a = Fix (RedBlackTreeF a)
```

The traditional benefit of a binary tree is being able to cut down search time by choosing whether to search further in the left or right subtree like so (in psuedocode):

```
fun member (x, E) = false
   | member (x, T (_, a, y, b)) =
     if x < y then member (x, a)
     else if x > y then member (x, b)
     else true
```

The function `member` will go left if the element that is being searched for is less than the current element and right if the opposite is true. It therefore improves search time to `O(logn)`.

However, in a recursion scheme, the algebra is recursively applied to the entire data structure. I've written an `member` algebra here:

```
memberPAlg :: Ord a => a -> RedBlackTreeF a Bool -> Bool    
memberPAlg _ EmptyRedBlackTreeF = False    
memberPAlg elem (RedBlackTreeNodeF _ left cur right) =    
        (elem == cur) || (left || right)
```

But it seems to be `O(nlogn)` rather than `O(logn)`. Is there any way to selectively recurse using a recursion scheme to save time complexity? Am I thinking about this the wrong way?

Comment: FWIW, your version is just O(n), with no log factor. It touches every node in the tree exactly once, doing a constant amount of work each time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of laziness, `left` and `right` are evaluated only if you ask for them. So, just compare the current node with the value being searched for to decide which subtree to go into:

```
memberPAlg :: Ord a => a -> RedBlackTreeF a Bool -> Bool    
memberPAlg _ EmptyRedBlackTreeF = False    
memberPAlg elem (RedBlackTreeNodeF _ left cur right) =    
   case compare elem cur of
     EQ -> True
     LT -> left
     GT -> right
```

Comment: Would something like this be possible for insert as well? It seems like the solution would have to be O(n) because a catamorphism or anamorphism would have to fully recurse?

Comment: @cocorudeboy For insert you'd need a paramorphism, so you can look at branches in their un-transformed states as well as the transformed result.